# Tool Tip for text in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, tooltip, ireport

What functionality in iReport allows for tool tip text?

I have a field name description that contains very large text. Instead of displaying large text I want to show two or three lines and rest of text as a tool tip. How is this possible?

Comment: That should be possible if you are exporting your report to HTML, or viewing it in JasperViewer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***hyperlinkTooltipExpression*** expression for *textField* element, for example.

You can find sample [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/hyperlink/index.html#hyperlinks).

In *iReport* you can call dialog for setting tooltip with help of context menu **Hyperlink**.

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

Comment: Hi @Alex, I am trying to get the tool tip working but somehow I am not able to achieve it. I took a text field and replaced its value by a column in database and then from its hyperlink property added a tool tip. What is the difference between "anchor text expression" and tool tip value?