# Tooltip for text / titles / headers in iReports

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am trying to have a tooltip text on mouseover on Column Header or any type of text field in Jasper iReports.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431346/tool-tip-for-text-in-ireport) which was not properly answered so i have to re-open it...

What i essentially need, is to show descriptive information of a column when user hovers his mouse pointer over the report in Jasper Server.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431346/tool-tip-for-text-in-ireport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ***hyperlinkTooltipExpression*** expression for *textField* element, for example.

You can find sample [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/hyperlink/index.html#hyperlinks).

In *iReport* you can call dialog for setting tooltip with help of context menu **Hyperlink**.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of Hyperlink Type 'None' I use 'LocalAnchor' then you get the hand tooltip on mouse-over.